# Determining when audio is ready to play

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am currently playing an audio file progressively like this:

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundLoaderContext;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var s:Sound = new Sound();
var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(5000, false);

s.load(new URLRequest('AUDIO URL'), context);
s.play();
```

which works great, but I want to know when it has enough data (based on the buffer time) and starts playing the file. To clarify, I am not trying to determine when the file has completely downloaded, I know that is done with `Event.COMPLETE`

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [ProgressEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/ProgressEvent.html)?

```
s.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);

function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {

    trace( event.bytesLoaded );
}
```

So when the bytesloaded is equal to the buffer amount, you know it.

---

Edit:

Perhaps you could check for the [isBuffering](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#isBuffering) attribute to see if the buffer is filled or not.

Comment: This approach does not work with different bitrates, (ie a file with a 128k bitrate will not have the same relative buffer time as a file with a 64k bitrate, and that does matter because if the bitrate is high, only a second or two of the file might be loaded.)

Comment: Perhaps you could use isBuffering attribute.